# What do ! and # mean when attached to numbers in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I have recently come across numeric literals such as 10! and 50# in Visual Basic programs. Could anyone tell me what these punctuation marks mean?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

They are called type declaration characters. [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191713) has more information.

```
  % Integer
  & Long
  ! Single
  # Double
  $ String
  @ Currency
```

Comment: Really? 123$ is the same as "123"? Wow - I never knew that!

Comment: This is true only for variable names, not for constant literals!

Comment: Yeah, I'd seen them in that context, but that didn't seem to be what the question was about...

Comment: @Michael Baker> you misunderstood the article. They AREN'T attached to literal, but to the variable name, and is used like `Dim x as String` => `Dim x$`

Comment: According the article: "Literals can also use the identifier type characters as can variables, constants, and expressions." Can you elaborate?

Comment: Has the hyperlink been edited? Within seconds I opened the same link twice and end up at two different articles! This one (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191713) relates to VB6 and doesn't mention literals. This one (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek(v=VS.71).aspx) talks about literals but relates to VB.NET.

Comment: @Michael Baker: I rolled back. The article about literals only applies to VB.NET and the question has only ever had the VB6 tag.

Comment: In VB6 you can use some of these characters - %&!#@ - with numeric literals to define the type. It's similar to the use in VB.Net although only the symbols are available, not the letters, and also a VB6 `Integer` is not the same as a VB.Net `Integer`. I'm just looking for a VB6 web link for you...

Comment: Normally, you'd see these attached to (numeric) literals in one of two places: is Const statements (since compiler constants are just replacement text, they can't have a "real" type); or when coercing a literal to Long, Double or Currency to avoid overflow (although I always preferred an explicit Ctype for maintainability).

Answer (score 16):

Using these characters specifies the data type of a numeric literal.

I thought this would be covered in the [VB6 manual online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338032(VS.60).aspx) but I can't find it.

However I just proved it with the [TypeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263394(v=VS.60).aspx) function in the VB6 IDE Immediate Window:

```
? typename(10!)
Single
?typename(10#)
Double
?typename(10%)
Integer
?typename(10&)
Long
?typename(10@)
Currency
```

PS Be aware that a VB6 `Integer` is 2 bytes, -32,768 to 32,767.

Answer (score 5):

****Here is a Cheat Sheet for DataTypes ****

Variable End with:

```
$ : String
% : Integer (Int16)
& : Long (Int32)
! : Single
# : Double
@ : Decimal
```

Start with:

```
&H : Hex
&O : Octal
```

Comparison between VB and VB.Net ([reference](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/datatypes.html))

Visual Studio .Net added Literal Types ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters))

Value End with: (For more complete list, refer the the reference)

```
S : Short (Int16)
I : Integer (Int32)
L : Long (Int64)
F : Single
R : Double
D : Decimal
```