# What does it mean to GetDC(0&)?

Tags: c#, vb6

I am reading some VB6 to convert to C#.  What does this line mean?  Is `0&` equivalent to `IntPtr.Zero`?

```
//'Get a Device context
hdc = GetDC(0&)
```

This value is used to pinvoke, so I'm not sure `IntPtr.Zero` makes sense since we need to be selecting some object.

```
OldFont = SelectObject(hdc, ObjFont)
```

Note, ObjFont is populated via

```
//'Get the Window's font
ObjFont = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0&)//there's that mysterious 0& agaain.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a (VB6) type declaration character. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888921/what-do-and-mean-when-attached-to-numbers-in-vb6) for more details on these.

In your example VB6 code it is forcing `0` to be a `Long` (4 bytes) as it would otherwise be an `Integer` (2 bytes)

It is the same as doing this long hand approach again VB6 code:

```
Dim lParam as Long
lParam = 0
ObjFont = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETFONT, 0, lParam)
```

Comment: So get the device context for zero?  What does that mean?  I think it's trying to get a handle to something.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey From MSDN: "If the parameter is NULL it gets the DC for the entire screen"

Comment: And as far as I know a VB6 `Long` is a 32 bit signed integer, e.g. equivalent to a `System.Int32` or using the C# alias `int`.

Answer (score 6):

In your specific example, yes, it's equivalent to `IntPtr.Zero` in C#.

It's the "null handle value" for VB6, that is used by [GetDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to return the device context for the entire screen.

Answer (score 3):

That's equivalent to passing `NULL` to `GetDC()` which instructs the function to return the `hDC` for the *entire screen*, so `IntPtr.Zero` is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as `Clng(0)` :) As the guy below said;D

Comment: In C Yes in VB6 it is the same as `Clng(0)`

Comment: In C# `0l` is 64 bit. In VB6 `0&` is 32 bit (and `0` is 16 bit).